# SQL query to LINQ to join 5 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have five tables which I am trying to get results from. Below are my table designs.

**Application and Environment** tables:

```
Id, Name
```

> NOTE - BOTH above tables have same properties.

**ResourceGroup** table:

```
Id, Name, Application_Id
```

**ResourceGroupEnvironment** table:

```
Id, ResourceGroup_Id, Environment_Id, VIP, URL
```

**Servers** table:

```
Id, ServerName, Alias, IPAddress, Network
```

**ServerResourceGroup** table:

```
Id, Server_Id, ResourceGroup_Id, Environment_Id
```

What results I am trying to get?

Based on above table design, I am expecting to get all servers that are part of `ResourceGroup` and `Application` table. `ResourceGroupEnvironment` and `ServerResourceGroup` table shares `environment` table where `ResourceGroupEnvironment` will have one common environment, but `ServerResourceGroup` can have multiple servers in that environment.

So from `ResourceGroupEnvironment` I am trying to join `VIP`, `URL` in to `servers`, but I get duplicate entries for servers, but each entry with different `vip` and `URL`. Please see below duplicate record in JSON for an example:

```
{
    "serverId": 1,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "Server1",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.1.1",
    "vip": "10.1.1.1",
    "url": "www.google.com",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
},
{
    "serverId": 1,
    "applicationName": "TestApp",
    "resourceName": "Test AppFabric",
    "serverName": "Server1",
    "aliasName": null,
    "os": "Windows Server 2008",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.1.1",
    "vip": "10.2.2.3",
    "url": "www.testui.com",
    "environmentName": "DEV",
}
```

So whats wrong with above records in JSON?

Well I should only get one record back from database for common`environment`. If there are multiple servers in `DEV` environment, then it should return multiple servers, but should join `VIP` and `URL` in to each server record. If you notice, `VIP` and `URL` are unique, which they belong to two different environments. Such as `10.1.1.1 VIP` belongs to `DEV` environment and `10.2.2.3` belongs to other environment `PROD`.

Here is the query I wrote in linq that is not working as excepted:

```
var query = from rg in _context.ResourceGroup
            join sr in _context.ServersResourceGroup on rg.Id equals sr.ResourceGroup_id
            join rge in _context.ResourceGroupEnvironment on sr.Environment_id equals rge.Environment_id into lrges
            from lrge in lrges.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join s in _context.Servers on sr.Server_id equals s.Id
            join e in _context.Environments on sr.Environment_id equals e.Id
            join a in _context.Applications on rg.Application_Id equals a.Id
            join d in _context.Domains on s.Domain_Id equals d.Id
            join t in _context.Types on rg.Type_Id equals t.Id
            join o in _context.OperatingSystems on s.OperatingSystem_Id equals o.Id
            join n in _context.NetworkZones on s.NetworkZone_Id equals n.Id
            join stat in _context.Status on s.Status.Id equals stat.Id
            where a.Name.ToLower() == applicationName.ToLower()
            select new SearchListViewModel()
            {
                serverId = s.Id,
                resourceName = rg.Name,
                applicationName = a.Name,
                serverName = s.ServerName,
                aliasName = s.Alias,
                os = o.OSVersion,
                ipAddress = s.IPAddress,
                vip = lrge.VIP,
                url = lrge.EndPointURL,
                domain = d.Name,
                network = n.Name,
                typeName = t.Name,
                environmentName = e.Name,
                status = stat.Name
            };

        return query.ToList();
```

**SQL Query:**

When I write my own SQL query, it works fine and gives me correct records. Please see below SQL query:

```
select rg.Name as ResourceName, s.ServerName, rge.VIP, rge.EndPointURL
from ResourceGroup as rg
join ServersResourceGroup as srg on rg.Id = srg.ResourceGroup_id
join Servers as s on srg.Server_id = s.Id
left join ResourceGroupEnvironment as rge on srg.Environment_id = rge.Environment_id
```

**HERE IS THE SOLUTION THAT WORKED AFTER EVERYONE'S HELP:**

```
 var query = from rg in _context.ResourceGroup
                    join srg in _context.ServersResourceGroup on rg.Id equals srg.ResourceGroup_id
                    join s in _context.Servers on srg.Server_id equals s.Id
                    join a in _context.Applications on rg.Application_Id equals a.Id
                    join e in _context.Environments on srg.Environment_id equals e.Id
                    join d in _context.Domains on s.Domain_Id equals d.Id
                    join t in _context.Types on rg.Type_Id equals t.Id
                    join n in _context.NetworkZones on s.NetworkZone_Id equals n.Id
                    join o in _context.OperatingSystems on s.OperatingSystem_Id equals o.Id
                    join stat in _context.Status on s.Status_Id equals stat.Id
                    join rge in _context.ResourceGroupEnvironment on srg.Environment_id equals rge.Environment_id into lrges
                    from lrge in lrges.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new SearchListViewModel()
                    {
                        serverId = s.Id,
                        serverName = s.ServerName,
                        aliasName = s.Alias,
                        domain = d.Name,
                        environmentName = e.Name,
                        network = n.Name,
                        os = o.OSVersion,
                        ipAddress = s.IPAddress,
                        vip = lrge == null ? string.Empty : lrge.VIP,
                        url = lrge == null ? string.Empty : lrge.EndPointURL,
                        typeName = t.Name,
                        applicationName = a.Name,
                        resourceName = rg.Name,
                        status = stat.Name
                    };

        return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Did you set your navigation properties? if so, you should try querying through them. I find it much easier than joining a bunch of tables.

Comment: ah, no I haven't. I should probably look in to that. :)

Comment: I count 11 joins in your Linq statement and 4 in your "hand written" sql statement that works. I do not really see how those are considered the same if you are testing to ensure you get a result using similar circumstances. Also if your database collation is not case sensitive then there is no reason to use a comparison with `.ToLower()`

Comment: thats true, there are more joins in linq query and hand written query, but mostly I am focusing on first 4 joins, all others are just inner join that doesnt really impact query execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query

```
SELECT rg.Name AS ResourceName, s.ServerName, rge.VIP, rge.EndPointURL
FROM ResourceGroup AS rg
JOIN ServersResourceGroup AS srg ON rg.Id = srg.ResourceGroup_id
JOIN Servers AS s ON srg.Server_id = s.Id
LEFT JOIN ResourceGroupEnvironment AS rge ON srg.Environment_id = rge.Environment_id
```

Can be translated to this Linq statement

```
var query = from rg in _context.ResourceGroup
    join srg in _context.ServersResourceGroup on rg.Id equals srg.ResourceGroup_id
    join s in _context.Servers on srg.Server_id equals s.Id
    from rge in _context.ResourceGroupEnvironment.Where(x => srg.Environment_id = x.Environment_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new{
        ResourceName = rg.Name, 
        s.ServerName, 
        rge.VIP, 
        rge.EndPointURL
    };
var queryResults = query.ToList();
```

Again you should really compare apples to apples. In your query you are joining 11 tables and you have a `where` clause which are both omitted from your example query which could be the reason for you different results. As per your comment though this answer just focuses on the 4 tables included in your SQL script.

---

About the last (outer) join: See answer on question [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558389/1260204,) by `@Stefan Steiger`. This is an easier to read syntax IMO but either that or the other way using the `join` syntax would work.

Comment: Hello, your example did help me make progress and I am able to make left join successfully. I will provide my answer to my question in Answer bulletin in my question.